# I am unable to login using linkedin integration module drupal 7?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, social-network

I have installed Drupal [linkedin Integration](http://drupal.org/project/linkedin) 7.x-1.x-dev and [Oauth module](https://drupal.org/project/oauth) .

I have entered the details like api key and secret key and all other settings properly

Now when I login using linkedin using the option as shown in the image
I am redirected to the page as shown in the image

[image]
[image]
but after I  enter linkedin credentials I am redirected to following page with no drupal user created
[image]

what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LinkedIn Integration module won't automatically create a new user account for you. From step 5 of the directions in the module's [README](http://drupalcode.org/project/linkedin.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt):

> Usage : Users will have to associate their LinkedIn account with their
>   local Drupal account (at user/%user/edit/linkedin) to use any
>   functionality provided by submodules.

So if you log in via LinkedIn with a LinkedIn account that isn't yet associated with a Drupal user account, you still need to create the new Drupal user account, and then the module will automatically associate the LinkedIn account with the new Drupal account in [a submit handler that it attaches to the user register form](http://drupalcode.org/project/linkedin.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/linkedin_auth/linkedin_auth.module#l150).

Comment: So by this module only if there is a drupal user with email id same as that provided into the linkedin will be able to synch ??

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with the module (we looked at it briefly but didn't end up using it)... I believe it saves the user association with a LinkedIn oauth token, not with an email address.

Comment: By moving to the link user/%user/edit/linkedin I was able to associate myself linkedin and I could login using Linkedin Thanks a  lot